# Restriction for identification of a indexing vector in sign function

Tags: vectors

Define the sign function $\text{sgn}(\cdot)$ as
$$\text{sgn}(z) = \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ z \ge 0, \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}$$ 
My problem turns to be I need to find a vector $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ where only $\text{sgn} (\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{\tau})$ matters.  Therefore, $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is not identifiable in this situation. Say, we have a solution, say $\boldsymbol{\tau}_0$. We can multiple it by any scalar positive number, say $c >0$. Then, $\text{sgn}(c\boldsymbol{x}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{\tau}_0)$ gives the same value.

Hence, my question is what are the possible restrictions we can use, so that $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is identifiable?

I can think of one way, that is to restrict $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ has norm one, i.e., $\| \boldsymbol{\tau}\|^2 = 1$. However, I need to do inference on $\boldsymbol{\tau}$. I feel like this may not be a possible way to restrict $\boldsymbol{\tau}$. Are there any other ways to work around this identification issue? Or, anyways to do inference on a unit ball?